# change no of lines after and before in git diff output

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to increase the number of lines displayed before and after changes in `git diff` output.

Analogous to `grep -A3 -B5 ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to `git diff --help`, `git diff` supports the same arguments as the standard `diff` command w/r/t context:

```
   -U<n>, --unified=<n>
       Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies
       -p.
```

Comment: Note the question suggested different before/after line counts (`-A3 -B5`) and `-U<n>` doesn't support that.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `-U` switch to control the number of lines of context around the diff:

```
$ git diff -U5
```